# opencv-3.0.0 on Raspberry error

Tags: python, c++

***HI i have this error in Opencv-3.0.0 on rasperry Pi***

```
enter cod# OpenCV_test1.py
```

## this program opens the file in the same directory names "image.jpg" and displays the original image and a Canny edges of the original image

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

#

def main():
    imgOriginal = cv2.imread("image.jpg")               # open image

```
if imgOriginal is None:                             # if image was not read successfully
    print "error: image not read from file \n\n"        # print error message to std out
    os.system("pause")                                  # pause so user can see error message
    return                                              # and exit function (which exits program)
# end if

imgGrayscale = cv2.cvtColor(imgOriginal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)        # convert to grayscale

imgBlurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale, (5, 5), 0)              # blur

imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgBlurred, 100, 200)                          # get Canny edges

cv2.namedWindow("imgOriginal", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)        # create windows, use WINDOW_AUTOSIZE for a fixed window size
cv2.namedWindow("imgCanny", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)           # or use WINDOW_NORMAL to allow window resizing

cv2.imshow("imgOriginal", imgOriginal)         # show windows
cv2.imshow("imgCanny", imgCanny)

cv2.waitKey()                               # hold windows open until user presses a key

cv2.destroyAllWindows()                     # remove windows from memory

return
```

#

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

e here

and this is the Error
*python OpenCV_test1.py*
  **File "OpenCV_test1.py", line 4
    import cv2 import numpy as np import os
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c++]? Also, please format your code and indent it properly.

Comment: Perhaps an issue with linebreak ?

Comment: Rolled back original question, since editors inserted line breaks that are most likely missing in the author's original code. Which is honestly clear from the SyntaxError that was generated.

@ceaser: Please edit your question with correct code formatting, **exactly** like it looks like in your editor, including line breaks.

Comment: The error states that there are multiple import statements per line (like in the original question text), which is a little bit misleading. Although I'm not aware of _Python_ being sensitive to *eoln*s you might want to check your source file using a hex editor for that: in _Ux_ should be `\n` (`\x0A`), _Win_: `\r\n`(`\x0D\x0A`), and on _Osx_: `\r` (`\x0D`).

Answer (score 0):

Imports must go on separate rows (or be be separated by semicolons, but please don't).

Change

```
import cv2 import numpy as np import os
```

to

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
```